# How to reset the default values for the properties of the component in the PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, windows, propertygrid

I have a class with properties as objects any more classes. For example:

```
    public Class Humans
    {
      public Person Human {get; set;}

      [DefaulValue("New York")]
      public string Sity {get; set;}
    }

    public struct Person
    {
      [DefaulValue("Name")]
      public string Name {get; set;}

      [DefaulValue("Surname")]
      public string Surname {get; set;}
    }
```

If I want to reset the Humans class, I write this:

```
    PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Humans);
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor pr in props)
    {
        if (pr.Attributes.OfType<DefaultValueAttribute>().Any())
        {
            pr.ResetValue(obj);
        }
    }
```

In the case of property, everything happens perfectly Sity, and for properties Human nothing happens. So here's how to reset to the default values ​​of these properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to check `.Attributes`. The key here is `pr.CanResetValue(obj)`. If that returns `true`, you can call `pr.ResetValue(obj)`. If it returns `false`, you shouldn't try. There are multiple approaches for supporting resets - including:

- `[DefaultValue]`
- `void Reset{membername}()`
- a custom `PropertyDesciptor`

I suggest you try adding:

```
void ResetHuman() { Human = null; }
```

Then you should find that `pr.CanResetValue(obj)` returns `true` and `pr.ResetValue(obj)` clears the value.

Comment: The fact is that I want to use the values of the reset method is not only for one class. Hence, it is necessary in each class to add a method Reset {membername}?